# numba doesn't parallelize range

Tags: python, jit, numba

I have loops in my code that I want to parallelize

```
from numba import njit, prange
from time import time


@njit
def f1(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                s += (i * k < j * j) - (i * k > j * j)
    return s


@njit
def f2(n):
    s = 0
    for i in prange(n):
        for j in prange(n):
            for k in prange(n):
                s += (i * k < j * j) - (i * k > j * j)
    return s


@njit(parallel=True)
def f3(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                s += (i * k < j * j) - (i * k > j * j)
    return s


@njit(parallel=True)
def f4(n):
    s = 0
    for i in prange(n):
        for j in prange(n):
            for k in prange(n):
                s += (i * k < j * j) - (i * k > j * j)
    return s


for f in [f1, f2, f3, f4]:
    d = time()
    f(2500)
    print('%.02f' % (time() - d))
```

I get the times:

```
27.44
27.34
26.83
13.05
```

I checked the activity of my processor, and while the first three functions were at 100%, the fourth was at ~300%.

I don't understand why specifying parallel didn't change anything and one needs to use prange. In [the doc](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html#examples), there is an example with range.

Comment: Interesting. This seems like a bug to me. I tried all combinations of `jit` and `njit`, with and without `nogil` and I always get 11 seconds on `f1` to `f3` and about 2.5s on `f4`. But afaik `parallel=True` is still an experimental feature. Perhaps you should file a bug report on `numba` github.

Comment: @Scotty1- Thanks for your help, I'll wait one day before reporting. Does nogil affect performance in general?

Comment: In my experience it does not, but I'm not using any concurrent threads. I just like to enable it to check if it *could* run in parallel without any conflicts.

Comment: Don't use prange on all loops (you would't do that with OpenMP either). Normally it is the goal to SIMD-vectorize the inner loops and parallelize over the outer loops for best performance. The fastmath keyword is also relevant for this type of operation. This will offer more algebraically correct optimizations that may have an impact on the numerical presicion (Summing by use of partial sums)

Answer (score 1):

From the Numba documentation:

> The experimental parallel=True option to @jit will attempt to optimize array operations and run them in parallel. It also adds support for prange() to explicitly parallelize a loop.

Now since you do not do any array operations in your function, there is nothing Numba can parallelize without explicitly marking the loops with prange.

So just to be sure there is no confusion.
Numba will only split your loop into threads when you set parallel=True in the decoration, and explictly marks the loops by changeing; range -> prange.

In your f4() you have put prange on all of the for loops, I would recommend only putting the prange on the outer most loop, because you don't want to risk spawning threads from threads.
I.e.:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def f5(n):
    s = 0
    for i in prange(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                s += (i * k < j * j) - (i * k > j * j)
    return s
```

Comment: Isn't s considered as a 0 dimensional array? Would it change if I initialized it as a numpy ndarray? Are you sure about nested prange? I don't think it works the same as OMP (for example). Did you mean process instead of thread?

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue on Github, and a contributor answered very precisely (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2960#issuecomment-388767318).

If he wants to repost his answer here, I'll accept it.